# Question about the 2nd law of thermo

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, entropy, biology

In some ways the 2nd law of thermodynamics appears to be violated by the creation of large molecules like proteins.

The reason this seems to be a violation is because individual atoms become much more constrained in their spatial movement in 3 dimensions.  If, for example, a hydrogen atom is attached to a larger object with more inertia, there is a reduction of probability of its translation with respect to other atoms in the molecule.  Therefore it has a reduction of probability in some microstates.  So there appears to be a reduction of entropy if you look purely at statistical mechanics.

However, if you consider the possible orbital states of its electrons, there is an increase.  The electron is able to inhabit many more orbital states as a part of the molecule.  The larger the molecule, presumably the more possible orbital states (not sure if that's how orbitals work tbh). Especially if you consider its position as part of a larger organism beyond just the protein.  In that case, there are many states this hydrogen atom can be in which previously had a probability of essentially 0 that now have a significant probability.

So can we say that actually the 2nd law is actually obeyed because of the new microstates that become available and drastically increased in probability? How can you account for these microstates of different types and combine them?

Answer (score 1):

2nd law of thermodynamics is not violated by proteins production in living organisms, because it states that entropy in the **isolated system** (which doesn't have energy in-flow from outside) must increase spontaneously. While cells in the production of proteins consumes [ATP compound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adenosine_triphosphate), which catalyzes chemical reactions of proteins. Thus due to ATP transmission between cells (and other chemicals as well),- cell is **not an isolated system** anymore. This means that reduction of entropy in created proteins (and even in cell itself if any) is pretty valid here and not forbidden, because of external energy use. Much like refrigerator also reduces internal entropy of air inside, but at the cost of consuming external energy,- electricity which is used in conditioning and heat pumping out of system.

Comment: Yes, I understand that explanation for the formation of the protein, but the energy from the ATP is only contributed once... so in that case how could a protein continue to exist in a stable local equilibrium despite having degrees of freedom constrained?

Comment: @scl Proteins break apart, this is called [Proteolysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proteolysis). This can happen due to hydrolysis or by other means.  Ornithine decarboxylase has half-life of 11 minutes, actin and myosin - a half-life about a month, DNA half-life is about [521 years](https://www.nature.com/articles/nature.2012.11555). So overall proteins are unstable.